# MySql Parameter must be defined mvc

Tags: mysql, model-view-controller

i have this code here:

```
var sql = "select shr_id, shc_id " +
                      "from tbox_operational.shipment_ref " +
                      "inner join tbox_operational.shipment_collo_ref using (shr_id) " +
                      "where shr_insdtm between ?dateTimeFrom";

var parameters = new List<MySqlParameter> {
                                           new MySqlParameter("?dateTimeFrom", dateTimeFrom.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"))                                                            
                                           };

            var query = (from db in context.Database.SqlQuery<ShridsModel>(sql, parameters)
                         select db).ToList();

            return query;
```

But it keeps me getting this error:

```
{"Parameter '?dateTimeFrom' must be defined."}
```

i have also in my connection string:

```
server=xxx;user id=runtime;password=xxxx;AllowUserVariables=True;
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved...

Instead of passing a list of the parameters, i pass each one individual and he recognizes it all